# How to build an index of S3 objects when data exceeds object metadata limit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

Building an index of S3 objects can be very useful to make them searchable quickly : the natural, most obvious way is to store additional data on the object meta-data and use a lambda to write in DynamoDB or RDS, as described here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/building-and-maintaining-an-amazon-s3-metadata-index-without-servers/

However, this strategy is limited by the amount of data one can store in the object metadata, which is 2KB, as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html. Suppose you need to build a system where every time an object is uploaded on S3 you store need to add some information not contained in the file and the object name to a database and this data exceeds 2KB:you can't store it in the object metadata.

What are viable strategies to keep the bucket and the index updated?

- Implement two chained API calls where each call is idempotent: if the second fails when the first succeed, one can retry until success. What happens if you perform a PUT of an identical object on S3, and you have versioning activated? Will S3 increase the version? In this case, implementing idempotency requires a single writer to be active at each time
- Use some sort of workflow engine to keep track of this two-step behaviour, such as AWS Step. What are the gotchas with this solution?

Comment: Hi @Edmondo1984, have you got any reply from anyone on this, or can you please share if you found any solution for this. I am thinking to design this without using Lamda functions, by just managing the data store in Dynamodb in my API. any thought will be greatly appreciated